# Creating React component libraries using TypeScript vs. Babel compiler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tsc

I am currently using the babel compiler to compile my React component libraries. I made this decision based on the fact that Create React App also uses the babel compiler. However, I am now finding that using babel to create libraries is more complicated. You need to introduce the TypeScript compiler anyway to generate type definitions. Thus I need to maintain two sets of configurations, babel and tsconfig. This complexity gets further amplified by the fact that I have multiple such libraries in a monorepo.

So my question is:

1. Is there any good reason to use the Babel TypeScript compiler to compile React libraries (vs tsc)?
2. Am I going to loose any features if I get rid of Babel completely and rely only on tsc?

Comment: It depends. If Webpack is used to compile the library, it might be even more problematic to set up popular typescript loaders (I personally stumbled upon slow compilation, memory usage issues and critical bugs a while ago). You actually lose some features (like `const enum`) with Babel.

Comment: Thanks @polkovnikov.ph. Personally, I am not using webpack. My published bundle only contains TypeScript compiled down to ES5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, it was clear to me that when creating a TypeScript library from scratch, it does not make sense to use the Babel compiler. Babel does not do any type checking of TS files. For that I have to run the TypeScript compiler anyway. Hence it is better to use the TypeScript compiler from the get go. For create-react-app, Babel was a better choice because they were. already using it for ES6 builds.

Furthermore, I picked up a CLI/template for creating my library. It's called [TXDX](https://tsdx.io/). It really makes the job of creating a TS library very easy.